# Office Communicator not shown in Pidgin ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, pidgin

I had a issue, while connecting to my office network, with ubuntu 14.04.
I used to connect well, when i had ubuntu13.04 installed. I was using Office Communicator protocol at that time. Recently i upgraded my ubuntu, and reinstalled pidgin. But this time “Office Communicator” does not show up as a protocol option.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: May be you need to reinstall sipe by doing:  


    sudo apt-get install pidgin-sipe

Answer (score 1):

The package pidgin-sipe provides Office Communicator support for Pidgin. It can be installed form the Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

You need

apt-get install libgstreamer1.0

This is a required dependency. Then it will show in the menu.